# Visual studio 2019 when debugging what is VMnnnn[dynamic]

Tags: visual-studio-2019

i am not using azure. in my VS start debugging (not start debugging without debug), i sometimes get VMnnnn[dynamic]. i have searched quite a bit for this but found only references to azure?

Comment: Where do you *get VMnnnn[dynamic)]*? Is that the entire content where you *get* it, or is there more information included?